# Could not import Django, working last week

Tags: python, django, pycharm

This was working last week,
when running python manage.py runserver 8080

I get this new error, a week after it was working fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: Are you running a virtual directory? The error suggests that you are running the project without activating it.

Which operating system are you using as the commands to activate a venv are different on Windows to Max and Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it does not find the django module.

- Where you usinga virtualenv? If True then you forgot to activate:

  `source venv/bin/activate`

  'venv' is the name of your virtual environment
- Have you tried to reinstall django module?

  `python -m pip install Django`

Comment: Cannot access pip during a corporate network, I had this working last week but suddenly after a week of working flawlessly, it stopped working....Why?!

Answer (score 0):

**I could try to keep reinstalling Django every time this happens, but
I found a solution**

**I am very confused why python manage.py runserver 8080 was working last week but not working this week! Very frustrating.**

I was facing similar issue. Pycharm was not showing and django options. To configure I did the following things:

go to edit configuration(run/debug menu)
In script path provide your manage.py location
in parameters provide 'runserver'
in python interpreter provide python location inside your virtual env
And now you can run and debug the django project using pycharm.

I can no longer execute Django from command line but only from PyCharm Run Manage.py Suddenly after a week of working with Django Flawlessly.

**Edit:** If you are having this problem, try restarting your computer, not PyCharm. Restarting the computer/machine was able to get me back into the following wonderful console runserver option.

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 03, 2020 - 12:22:19
Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Phew! Why this happened, I will never know.